# Adding BrowserRouter to render components in a specific div in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React newbie here. I want to create a side navigation bar using React Router than renders components on the basis of whatever link is clicked. I'm getting increasingly confused on how and where I should place my browser router.

This is a snippet of my index.js file

```
ReactDOM.render(<Header/>, document.getElementById('header'));
ReactDOM.render(<SideBar/>, document.getElementById('sidebar'));
ReactDOM.render(<Footer/>, document.getElementById('footer'));
```

There is also an element with ID = mainBody in which I want to render components that are added/replaced depending on what I click on my sidebar.

I have a heading component as of now that I want to change.

The following is a component SideNav that the SideBar component imports. This handles the routing links.

```
<BrowserRouter>
            <li className="st-bottom-line">
                    <Link to="/Dashboard">Dashboard </Link>
            </li>

            <li className="st-bottom-line">
                    <Link to='/Configuration'> Configuration </Link>
            </li>               
            <div>
                    <Route path="/Dashboard" render={(props) => <Heading {...props} name={`Dashboard`} />} />
                    <Route path="/Configuration" render={(props) => <Heading {...props} name={`Configuration`} />} />
            </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

As you can imagine, right now when I click on any of the two links, the Heading component appears in the SideBar itself.

What changes should I make so that the Heading appears in another component? I've seen countless examples of sidenavs and routing but I'm still really confused because what I'm trying to make is structurally different.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please add code for mainBody

Comment: @JatinParmar There isn't any code for mainBody at the moment. I've simply created a div with that ID in my index.html file. (I'm creating this application using the create-react-app). The idea that I had in mind was to simply use the element ID and render elements in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to change the way you structure your app. The convention is to have only one ReactDOM.render() that renders a HOC component (e.g. Your App Component) which then it renders various child components based on your **Route**s defined in **BrowserRouter**.

Here is a simple structure that actually works:

*index.html:*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*index.js:*

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

*App.js*

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

export const App: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <div>
        // This sidebard will be rendered on each route, because it's outside of <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="sideBar">
           <ul>
              <li className="st-bottom-line">
                    <Link to="/Dashboard">Dashboard </Link>
              </li>

              <li className="st-bottom-line">
                    <Link to='/Configuration'> Configuration </Link>
              </li>          
           </ul>
        </div>

        // This BrowserRouter will render the proper component based on the current URL (i.g. 'localhost:3000/Dashboard')
        <BrowserRouter>
                  <Route path="/Dashboard" render={(props) => <Heading {...props} name={`Dashboard`} />} />
                  <Route path="/Configuration" render={(props) => <Heading {...props} name={`Configuration`} />} />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: So even for components such as Footer and Header is it better to render them in my App.js file rather than the index.js file?

Comment: By convention, it's better to leave the index.js as simple as possible, add your shared components (Header and Footer) in App.js just like I added the Sidebar. You can see dozens of examples in the web, like: https://github.com/eh3rrera/react-router-4-example/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks!